# Python looping two different dataFrames to create a new column

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I want to add a new column to a dataframe by referencing another dataframe.

I want to run an if statement using startswith method to match df1['BSI'] column to df2['initial'] to assign the corresponding df2['marker'], and give df1 a new column that consists of markers, which I will use for cartopy marker style.

I am having trouble looping df2 inside a df1 loop. I basically can't figure out how to call df1 item onto df2 loop to compare to df2 items.

df1 looks like this:

```
    BSI     Shelter_Number  Location                            Latitude    Longitude
0   AA-010  1085            SUSSEX (N SIDE) & RIDEAU FALLS      45.439571   -75.695694
1   AA-030  3690            SUSSEX (E SIDE) & ALEXANDER NS      45.442795   -75.692322
2   AA-180  279             CRICHTON (E SIDE) & BEECHWOOD FS    45.439556   -75.676849
3   AA-200  2018            BEECHWOOD (S SIDE) & CHARLEVOIX NS  45.441154   -75.673622
4   AA-220  3301            BEECHWOOD (S SIDE) & MAISONNEUVE NS 45.442188   -75.671356
```

df2 looks like this:

```
    initial marker
0   AA      bo
1   AB      bv
2   AC      b^
3   AD      b<
4   AE      b>
```

desired output is:

```
BSI, Shelter_Number, Location, Latitude, Longitude, marker

0
AA-010 1085 SUSSEX (N SIDE) & RIDEAU FALLS 45.439571 -75.695694 bo

1
AA-030 3690 SUSSEX (E SIDE) & ALEXANDER NS 45.442795 -75.692322 bo

2
AA-180 279 CRICHTON (E SIDE) & BEECHWOOD FS 45.439556 -75.676849 bo

3
AA-200 2018 BEECHWOOD (S SIDE) & CHARLEVOIX NS 45.441154 -75.673622 bo

4
AA-220 3301 BEECHWOOD (S SIDE) & MAISONNEUVE NS 45.442188 -75.671356 bo
```

Comment: Can you post your dataframes in such a way that they are easy to replicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a dictionary from your `df2` and then map `df1` to create the new column. If all of your entries in `BSI` are the same format as provided, then it's simple to just select the first 2 letters. If if it needs to be more complicated, like all things before the first hyphen, then you can use regex.

Here's some test data

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'BSI': ['AA-010', 'AA-030', 'AA-180', 'AA-200', 'AA-220'],
                    'Latitude': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'initial': ['AA', 'AB', 'AC', 'AD', 'AE'],
                    'marker': ['bo', 'bv', 'b^', 'b<', 'b>']})
```

Here's the mapping

```
dct = pd.Series(df2.marker.values, index=df2.initial).to_dict()
df1['marker'] = df1['BSI'].str[0:2].map(dct)

      BSI  Latitude marker
0  AA-010         1     bo
1  AA-030         2     bo
2  AA-180         3     bo
3  AA-200         4     bo
4  AA-220         5     bo
```

Answer (score 1):

Use map. Infact there are many similar answers using map but the only difference here is that you are using only a part of BSI in df1 for matching

```
df1['marker'] = df1['BSI'].str.extract('(.*)-', expand = False).map(df2.set_index('initial').marker)



    BSI     Shelter_Number  Location                            Latitude    Longitude   marker
0   AA-010  1085            SUSSEX (N SIDE) & RIDEAU FALLS      45.439571   -75.695694  bo
1   AA-030  3690            SUSSEX (E SIDE) & ALEXANDER NS      45.442795   -75.692322  bo
2   AA-180  279             RICHTON (E SIDE) & BEECHWOOD FS     45.439556   -75.676849  bo
3   AA-200  2018            BEECHWOOD (S SIDE) & CHARLEVOIX NS  45.441154   -75.673622  bo
4   AA-220  3301            BEECHWOOD (S SIDE) & MAISONNEUVE NS 45.442188   -75.671356  bo
```